# Láska skala - English word play exists?

Tags: repetition, word-games

In Slovak language there are these two words:
*láska* (love) and *skala* (rock)

If you keep repeating any of above words, it kind of merges into another one, e.g.:

```
la[skala][skala]ska...
ska[laska][laska]la...
```

Does English version of this word play exist? Can you think of some English words?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is far too broad. Pairs include:
*Bela Abel,
beta abet,
calami amical,
casaba abacas,
chemical alchemic,
chilla achill,
dama Adam,
Dantean andante,
ethical alethic,
glean angle,
idea aide,
lastage agelast,
lexica alexic,
locational allocation,
loofa aloof,
loyal alloy,
missa amiss,
muleta amulet,
overall allover,
pineal alpine,
tarsal altars,
tchai aitch,
ternal altern,
truistical altruistic,
vineal alvine.*

Comment: @tchrist to narrow it, maybe question is: does this word play exist?

Comment: It might exist  but I don't know it if it does. There are so many possibilities that must surely be dreamt up all the time. It would probably be common words like *enlist/listen, ringer/erring, server/verser, mother/thermo, ablest/stable.* I would think swapped compound words like *sidetrack/trackside* or *boathouse/houseboat* wouldn't count, nor would pairs that are the same as each other like *couscous* or *bonbon*.

Comment: Numerous phrases in English are subject to the same merging of pronunciation through rapid repetition in speech, despite their dissimilarity in sense—for example, "no notion" and "known ocean."

Comment: skala doesn't have an accent, so they are not the same word.

Answer (score 1):

> artsartsarts...

is *arts* or *tsar*.

Basically, you need a word which can be written as AB, with A and B partitioning substrings of the word, where BA is a word too.

In my example A=ar and B=ts.

I can't imagine there are that many non-trivial (like SIGN-POST if this worked) examples with 5 or more letters.

Comment: There are a few, but they all seem to just swap words.

Comment: Please add examples suggested in the comments, then we can accept this post.